# No module named 'transformers' - trouble importing Python library

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm using Windows 10.

I have installed the `transformers` package.

```
py -m pip show transformers


Name: transformers
Version: 4.18.0
Summary: State-of-the-art Natural Language Processing for TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch
Home-page: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
Author: Thomas Wolf, Lysandre Debut, Victor Sanh, Julien Chaumond, Sam Shleifer, Patrick von Platen, Sylvain Gugger, Suraj Patil, Stas Bekman, Google AI Language Team Authors, Open AI team Authors, Facebook AI Authors, Carnegie Mellon University Authors
Author-email: thomas@huggingface.co
License: Apache
Location: c:\users\polga\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: filelock, huggingface-hub, numpy, packaging, pyyaml, regex, requests, sacremoses, tokenizers, tqdm
Required-by:
```

However when I import it with `import transformers` I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'
```

This happens wit both Spyder and Google Colab. However when I do `import pandas` in both environments the package is imported correctly. I'm using a new computer and this hadn't happened to me before. What could the difference in behaviour be due to?

Comment: Checkout: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2478

Comment: how you install `transformers` module.

Comment: I have installed it with the `py -m pip install transformers` command.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have python2 and python3?

If yes maybe try:

`pip3 install transformers`

Comment: I have Python 3.10.4, however when I do `py -m pip3 install transformers` it says `No module named pip3`.

Comment: @zest16 `pip3 install` runs **a script** named `pip3`. `py -m pip3` runs **a module or package** named `pip3`. `pip` has only one **package** named `pip` but it could have any number of **scripts** named `pip`, `pip3`, `pip310`, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following. I'm using `py -m pip3 install transformers` because that's what I've used for other libraries (e.g. `py -m pip3 install pandas`). If I ran `pip3 install transformers` I would get `"pip3" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.` (`pip3` is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Check properly if it's related to rust compiler then first install rust compiler.

```
pip install setuptools-rust
```

Then install transformer of 2.5.1 version.

```
pip install transformers==2.5.1
```

If you already install rust and no such error then install transformer only.

```html
pip install transformers==2.4.1
```

Credit goes to DGBSD.
For more information visit [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2831)